# Issue in code to guess random number

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple python code to guess a random number between 1 and 20. For the incorrect guess, the system shows intended message but for the correct guess it is not giving the proper output.

Could someone help me understand the issue in the below code

```
import random
import sys
answer=random.randint(1,20)
nt=0
cg=0
while cg!=answer:
 nt=nt+1
 print('Guess the correct number')
 cg=input()
 if cg==answer:
   print('Congrats! You have guessed correctly in'  + str(nt) + ' tries')
   sys.exit()
 print('Guess is incorrect. Please try again. Answer is ' + str(answer) + ' in  ' + str(nt) + ' tries')
 continue
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Comment: `cg = int(input())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cg=input()`, `input()` return type in 'str'.  So the condition `cg==answer` will always be false.

Use:

```
cg=int(input())
```

instead of

```
cg=input()
```

read more about `input()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Thanks a lot JkShaw!!